# Atoms and Integers in List in prolog

Tags: prolog

How to write a rule for the following output?

```
?- atoms_and_integers([a,b,1,2])
```

Output:

```
Number of Atoms:2
Number of integers:2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this isn't homework, in which case I don't want to be partner in crime and will say that the following code is free to be used by anyone for any purpose other than cheating on their homework :-)

```
atoms_and_integers(L) :-
    atoms_and_integers_aux(L, Atoms, Integers),
    writeln(['Atoms: ', Atoms]),
    writeln(['Integers: ', Integers]).

atoms_and_integers_aux([], 0, 0).
atoms_and_integers_aux([H|T], Atoms, Integers) :-
    atom(H), !,
    atoms_and_integers_aux(T, AtomsT, Integers),
    Atoms is AtomsT + 1.    
atoms_and_integers_aux([H|T], Atoms, Integers) :-
    integer(H), !,
    atoms_and_integers_aux(T, Atoms, IntegersT),
    Integers is IntegersT + 1.    
atoms_and_integers_aux([_H|T], Atoms, Integers) :-
    atoms_and_integers_aux(T, Atoms, Integers).
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this will be of little help for your assignment, but I'm a fan of library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) !

```
atoms_and_integers(L, NAs, NIs) :-
    aggregate(count, E^(member(E, L), atom(E)), NAs),
    aggregate(count, E^(member(E, L), integer(E)), NIs).
```

Comment: (+1) I've learned more about `aggregate/3` from you CapelliC than anyone. :)